# How to put method in Map, the method comes from Class.forName().getMethods()?

Tags: java

My goal is to put method inside the `Map<String, Supplier<String>>`

What I have done:

1. Try it to put method from the same class.

```
    Map<String, Supplier<String>> local = new HashMap<String, Supplier<String>>() {{
      put("GET /hi", () -> sayHi());
      put("GET /hello", () -> sayHello());
    }};
```

What I need to do:

1. Get method from other class using `Class.forName().getMethods()`.
2. Put the method inside the `Map`.

```
    for (Method methodz : clazz.getMethods()) {
      if (methodz.isAnnotationPresent(GetMapping.class)) {
        requestMappings.put("GET /hi", () -> methodz());
      }
    }
```

My expected result: It should work.

My actual result: It throws error `Method call expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you need to invoke your method

```
() -> methodz.invoke(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a piece of code that does exactly that. I've changed the annotation just to have all the parts in one piece (not depending on anything else). One thing is, that I couldn't get annotations with `getMethods()` but with `getDeclaredMethods()`. Another thing is that I couldn't manage to do the dynamic part without the `try`/`catch`. It's pretty basic code, so sorry for all the `System.out`s and `throws Exception`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface SomeAnnotation {
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        MyClass single = new MyClass();
        single.doThatThing();
    }
    
    private void doThatThing() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Supplier<String>> local = new HashMap<String, Supplier<String>>() {{
            put("GET /hi", () -> sayHi());
            put("GET /hello", () -> sayHello());
        }};
        
        System.out.println(local);

        Map<String, Supplier<String>> other = new HashMap<String, Supplier<String>>();
        for (Method methodz : this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (methodz.isAnnotationPresent(SomeAnnotation.class)) {
                other.put("GET /" + methodz.getName().toLowerCase().substring(3), () -> {
                    try {
                        return (String) methodz.invoke(this);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(other);
    }
    
    @SomeAnnotation
    String sayHi() {
        return "Hi!";
    }
    @SomeAnnotation
    String sayHello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Comment: yup, I assume `getMethods()` return the whole methods of `Object`, including declared methods. I think it's a bug. Anyway, what do you mean by dynamic? Do you mean `/hi` and `/hello`. I put it on the `@SomeAnnotation("/hi")`. Then, I would call, on your code `SomeAnnotation annotation = methodz.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class)` then call `annotation.value()`.

Comment: Sorry I meant the `(String) methodz.invoke(this)` part, the method to be called would be determined dynamically, basically at runtime not instead of compile time. The idea with the annotation value is good, I would have done that too but I didn't want to change your original standing point. Well I wish you good luck and success!

Comment: Oh and `getMethods()` didn't work because my methods weren't `public`. It only returns `public` methods.